# React TypeScript thinks key in object doesn't exists

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I have a component with the following props:

```
type Props =
    | {
            type: "first";
            obj: {someKey: string};
      }
    | {
            type: "second";
            obj: {someKey: string, anotherKey: string};
      };
```

When I pass `type="second"` and I'm trying to access the `anotherKey` in obj I get an error that `anotherKey` might not exist, although I specified in the props that when the type is `second` obj has a key named `anotherKey`.

Is there any way to make this work?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need `if` to check if it's second type

```
if (props.type === 'second') {
   props.obj.anotherKey
}
```